# http request does not fire using new WebClient()

Tags: .net, vb.net

Using the following code, I receive no error but I am not able to make post data using http.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
 Imports System.Timers
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Main Start")
        Static aTimer As System.Timers.Timer
        aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(20000)

        AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
        aTimer.Interval = 2000
        aTimer.Enabled = True

        Console.ReadLine()
        GC.KeepAlive(aTimer)

    End Sub

    Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime)
        Dim deviceId As String = Environment.MachineName
        Dim message As String = "test from vb"

        Console.WriteLine("Message is: " + message)
        Console.WriteLine("MachineName is: " + deviceId)

        Dim postData = String.Format("DeviceId={0}&Message={1}", _
          WebUtility.UrlEncode(deviceId), _
          WebUtility.UrlEncode(message))

        Console.WriteLine("postData is: " + postData)

        Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
        myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

        Dim responseArray = myWebClient.UploadData("http://ournicesite.com/api/notification", "POST", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData))
        Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        Console.WriteLine(responseArray)
        Dim response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not able"? What _does_ happen, does your `OnTimedEvent` get called, what is `responseArray`?

Comment: responseArray lenght 0

Comment: Then apparently the server doesn't return a response body. The result may be a `204 No Content`, meaning the POST was executed successfully but the server didn't return a body. What do you **expect** to get in return?

Comment: thanks for your comment yes I get a 204 No content. Posting to that specif url from an html form I receive an URL. Using above code I cannot get any result

Comment: it seems that the value in the POST are not sent to the server. do you have any idea? many thanks